# Realm, Accessing the Object property after deleting that Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, realm, mongodb-realm

I am deleting a Realm db Object, but I want to access its value after deleting so that I can use it in other processings.
This is how my code looks like:

```
const theObject = realm.objects('Products').filtered("_id == $0", "61bba17fc7e82eaae53527de")

//the fetched theObject(response) looks like this: 
[{_id:'61bba17fc7e82eaae53527de', name: 'Sugar'}]

var productName = theObject[0].name

realm.write(() => {

 realm.delete(theObject)

})

return productName //I want to use this productName here to do some other stuffs
```

I want to use/return the productName for doing some other things, but when i try to access it, i find it *undefined* or *null*.

I think this is caused because the theObject has been deleted and hence the productId can't be acceced, but I wonder why it is that way since i already caught that id initially when I assigned it before deleting. ie `productName = theObject[0].name`

Now,My question is, How can I still get/access/return that productName?

Comment: You can't delete objects in JS, only Garbage Collector can do that. You have only deleted a reference to an object (a property) from `realm`.

Comment: @Teemu Now after deleting that reference to an object, How can I access that *productName*? What should be the solution to my problem?

Comment: If you run your code, `productName` still contains what was assigned to it.

Comment: @Teemu SOLVED. The productName was returning an array of one object ie [{}], so I  solved it by accesing that object and finding the value

Answer (score 0):

This shouldn't be possible. Comment out the delete, and console log productName to ensure things are behaving as you think they are.

Also it looks like your missing a var/let/const for productName

```
const productName = theObject[0].name
```

Edit:

Since these are async operations its possible that `real.objects('Prodcuts')` is losing the race to `realm.delete()`. You can solve this by awaiting your access request before attempting to deleting.

Comment: I should not comment out the delete because I WANT THAT DOC TO BE DELETED.
The issue here is, I fetch the Object and get its value for other uses(the returned productName) and then I delete the Object. How can I do this?

Comment: Of course YOU WANT THE DOC TO BE DELETED. But for testing purposes, you should comment it out to ensure you're able to fetch the product in the first place.

Comment: I SOLVED IT, The productName was returning an array of one object ie [{}], so I solved it by accesing that object and finding the value